# Generating a faulty report when running JMeter 3.0 test with Ant

Tags: html, ant, jmeter

I have been at it for days. Basically I want to create a HTML report from JMeter test file, using Ant. I am using Linux Ubuntu 16.04.1. Here is my build.xml :

```
<project name="performance-tests" default="run-performance-tests" basedir=".">
<property name="testpath" value="${user.dir}"/>
<poperty name="jmeter.home" value="/home/richard/Asjad/apache-jmeter-3.0"/>

<!-- Name of test (without .jmx) -->
<property name="test" value="Test"/>

<path id="jmeter.path">
  <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="/*.jar" />
</path> 

<target name="run-performance-tests">
  <delete dir="${basedir}/target" quiet="true" failonerror="false"/>
<mkdir dir="${basedir}/target"/>

<!-- Allow jar to be picked up locally -->
<path id="jmeter.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}">
      <include name="ant-jmeter*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

  <taskdef name="jmeter"
    classpathref="jmeter.classpath"
    classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.JMeterTask" />
  <echo message="Running load tests in testing.xml"/>
  <jmeter
       jmeterhome="${jmeter.home}"
       testplan ="${testpath}/${test}.jmx"
       resultlog="${basedir}/target/JMeterResults.xml">
    <jvmarg value="-Xincgc"/>
    <jvmarg value="-Xmx512m"/>
    <jvmarg value="-Dproperty=value"/>
    <property name="request.threads" value="5"/>
    <property name="request.loop" value="50"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results" value="all"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>

  </jmeter>
  <xslt in="${basedir}/target/JMeterResults.xml"
    out="${basedir}/target/Test.html"
    style="${basedir}/jmeter-results-detail-report.xsl"/>
</target>
```

This is what I see when I run the script:

```
Buildfile: /home/richard/Asjad/apache-jmeter-3.0/extras/build.xml

run-performance-tests:
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/richard/Asjad/apache-jmeter-3.0/extras/target
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/richard/Asjad/apache-jmeter-3.0/extras/target
     [echo] Running load tests in testing.xml
   [jmeter] Executing test plan: /home/richard/Asjad/apache-jmeter-3.0/extras/TestPlan/Test.jmx ==> /home/richard/Asjad/apache-jmeter-3.0/extras/target/JMeterResults.xml
   [jmeter] Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
   [jmeter] Writing log file to: /home/richard/Asjad/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin/jmeter.log
   [jmeter] Creating summariser <summary>
   [jmeter] Created the tree successfully using /home/richard/Asjad/apache-jmeter-3.0/extras/TestPlan/Test.jmx
   [jmeter] Starting the test @ Fri Jul 29 11:57:25 EEST 2016 (1469782645099)
   [jmeter] Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
   [jmeter] summary =     10 in 00:00:02 =    4.6/s Avg:   214 Min:   105 Max:   344 Err:     0 (0.00%)
   [jmeter] Tidying up ...    @ Fri Jul 29 11:57:27 EEST 2016 (1469782647345)
   [jmeter] ... end of run
     [xslt] Processing /home/richard/Asjad/apache-jmeter-3.0/extras/target/JMeterResults.xml to /home/richard/Asjad/apache-jmeter-3.0/extras/target/Result_One.html
     [xslt] Loading stylesheet /home/richard/Asjad/apache-jmeter-3.0/extras/jmeter-results-detail-report.xsl

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
```

The build succeeds and then it gives me a HTML file and when I open it I see this:
[HTML report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMzuu.png)

I would be really thankful if someone could at least tell me my mistake or direction I am supposed to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like JMeter developers broke `jmeter-results-detail-report.xsl` file, bug was reported here:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59918
  It will be fixed in next Apache JMeter version 3.1.

In order to revert to previous behaviour take the following steps:

1. Download [apache-jmeter-2.13.zip](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-2.13.zip)
2. Extract `jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl` file from `apache-jmeter-2.13/extras` folder and drop it to "extras" folder of your JMeter 3.0 installation
3. Modify your `build.xml` file to use `jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl` file like:

   ```
   <xslt in="${basedir}/target/JMeterResults.xml"
       out="${basedir}/target/Test.html"
       style="${basedir}/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl"/>
   ```

Alternatively you can get XSLT file i.e. from [here](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/benchmark/scripts/SHARE/share-0002/3.4.6/templates/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl)

See [Visualizing JMeter .jtl Files Viewed as An .xsl Stylesheet](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/visualizing-jmeter-jtl-files-viewed-xsl-stylesheet) article for more details on transforming JMeter XML result files to HTML format.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug that I reported here:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59918

It will be fixed in next Apache JMeter version 3.1 or 3.0.1.

You can test if it's ok by using nightly build present here:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

Why still use Ant + xslt to generate a report while since 3.0 you have a new web report with lots of dynamic graphsand tables with significant metrics.

See :

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13167322)

Comment: I updated my answer. I am not criticizing the reporter, I am providing information on more up to date ways to generate report, thing that user may ignore.