# Generating HTML report with Ant 1.9.7 from Jmeter 3.0 file - "Start and end within the same entity" Error

Tags: ant, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

Here is basically the build.xml that Jmeter 3.0 generated itself. When I try to run the tests with 40 000 users within an hour I get the error after 17 minutes - 
 "${path}/build.xml: Fatal error during transformation using ${path}/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.; SystemID: file:${path}/Test.jtl;"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="ant-jmeter" default="all">
    <property name="testpath" value="${user.dir}"/>
    <property name="jmeter.home" value="${basedir}/.."/>
    <property name="report.title" value="Load Test Results"/>
    <property name="target.report.dir" location="Asjad/apache-jmeter-3.0/extras/report"/>

    <property name="test" value="Test"/>

    <property name="show-data" value="n"/>

    <property name="format" value="2.1"/>

    <condition property="style_version" value="">
        <equals arg1="${format}" arg2="2.0"/>
    </condition>

    <condition property="style_version" value="_21">
        <equals arg1="${format}" arg2="2.1"/>
    </condition>

    <condition property="funcMode">
        <equals arg1="${show-data}" arg2="y"/>
    </condition>

    <condition property="funcMode" value="false">
      <not>
        <equals arg1="${show-data}" arg2="y"/>
      </not>
    </condition>

    <path id="jmeter.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}">
          <include name="ant-jmeter*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <taskdef
        name="jmeter"
        classpathref="jmeter.classpath"
        classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.JMeterTask"/>

    <target name="all" depends="run,report"/>

    <target name="run">
        <echo>funcMode = ${funcMode}</echo>
        <delete file="${testpath}/${test}.html"/>
    <delete file="${testpath}/${test}.jtl"/>
        <jmeter
            jmeterhome="${jmeter.home}"
            testplan ="${testpath}/${test}.jmx"
            resultlog="${testpath}/${test}.jtl">

            <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
            <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results" value="all"/>
            <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes" value="true"/>
            <property name="file_format.testlog" value="${format}"/>
            <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error" value="${funcMode}"/>
        </jmeter>
    </target>

    <property name="lib.dir" value="${jmeter.home}/lib"/>

    <path id="xslt.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="xalan*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="serializer*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <target name="report" depends="xslt-report">
        <echo>Report generated at ${report.datestamp}</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="xslt-report" depends="_message_xalan">
        <tstamp><format property="report.datestamp" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"/></tstamp>
        <xslt
            classpathref="xslt.classpath"
            force="true"
            in="${testpath}/${test}.jtl"
            out="${testpath}/${test}.html"
            style="${basedir}/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl">
            <param name="showData" expression="${show-data}"/>
            <param name="titleReport" expression="${report.title}"/>
            <param name="dateReport" expression="${report.datestamp}"/>
        </xslt>
    </target>

        <condition property="xalan.present">
           <and>
             <available classpathref="xslt.classpath" classname="org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
             <available classpathref="xslt.classpath" classname="org.apache.xml.serializer.ExtendedContentHandler"/>
         </and>
       </condition>

     <target name="_message_xalan" unless="xalan.present">
         <echo>Cannot find all xalan and/or serialiser jars</echo>
        <echo>The XSLT formatting may not work correctly.</echo>
        <echo>Check you have xalan and serializer jars in ${lib.dir}</echo>
     </target>

</project>
```

It is a simple test that just makes requests to the webpage. 
I am using Ant build 1.9.7 and Jmeter 3.0.

Comment: any feedback on answer ?, if ok you should accept it and upvote so that users can confidently use it, thx

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 possible reasons:

1. Ant might be trying to convert .jtl to HTML when the .jtl is incomplete. In order to work that around:

   - Add the next line to `<jmeter>` section:

     ```
     <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush" value="true"/>
     ```
   - Or alternatively put add the following line to *user.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder)

     ```
     jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
     ```

   It will "tell" JMeter to store the results as soon as they arrive.
2. 40 000 users is quite a "heavy" load and JMeter default configuration might not be suitable for this. I believe you need to add at least some [Java Heap space](https://crunchify.com/jvm-tuning-heapsize-stacksize-garbage-collection-fundamental/). In case of Ant it would be adding the next lines to `<jmeter>` section:

   ```
   <jvmarg value="-Xmx8G"/>
   ```

   Change that `8G` reference value to be around 80% of your available physical RAM. [See 9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide for more recommendations on JMeter tuning for maximum performance

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions but neither of these worked.

Comment: What's in *jmeter.log* file?

Answer (score 0):

Showing your jmeter.log file (jmeter 3.0 will tell you where it is generated) will help.

But you may be facing this bug if using ANT + XSL to generated report:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59918

See this :

- [Generating a faulty report when running JMeter 3.0 test with Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38654937/generating-a-faulty-report-when-running-jmeter-3-0-test-with-ant)